# Where do you place the_content(); in wordpress to enable Youtube videos on the home page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

If you visit [this site](http://vecnamusic.com) you will find that it's just posts, with YouTube videos on the landing. However, I would like the YouTube videos to appear on the homepage, I've run into this problem before with WordPress. I would go in and change `the_excerpt();` to `the_content();`. However, these pages do not call for `the_excerpt();`, so I'm thinking that I need to add `the_content();` to a particular page and position in the coding. Is anybody familiar at the location to call `the_content()`?

Comment: http://vecnamusic.com

Answer (score 1):

`the_content();` must be called from inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Otherwise there are no requirements where you place it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are looking for, because your question seems very confusing to me, but you can add a front-page.php file to your theme, which will enable you to customize your lay-out for your homepage specifically.